# Why does きいろ mean yellow rather than green?

Tags: meaning, etymology, colors

I know that most of "why" questions don't make much sense as far as linguistics are concerned but I'll ask anyway.

I know that  き means a tree. いろ means color. It doesn't take a genius to guess that きいろ (lit. tree color) should mean green. But it means yellow. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: For me the colour of a tree is brown (green is the colour of the leaves). And yellow is just a lighter brown.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There was a word, 木色【きいろ】 "the colour of trees",  recorded in the *Vocabulário da Língua do Japão*. But actually, 黄【き】 on its own already means "yellow".

木 and 黄 are most likely *not* etymologically related. We know that 木 had a type-2 (乙類) /ki/ in Old Japanese. If we knew that 黄 had a type-1 (甲類) /ki/, then we could definitively say that the two are etymologically unrelated. This diagnostic is the reason why we say that 神【かみ】 and 上【かみ】 are unrelated words: the former has a type-2 /mi/, while the latter has a type-1 /mi/. However, we *do* know the modern accentuation patterns of 木 and 黄, and they are different:

- 木 is accented in modern standard Japanese, 黄 is not.
- 木【きい】 is low register unaccented (→ LH) in modern Kyoto dialect, 黄【きい】 is high register unaccented (→ HH).

Assuming these continue a historical distinction, it seems safe to conclude that 木 and 黄 were not the same word in Old Japanese as well.

Comment: I understand that some researchers reconstruct 乙類 /i/ is as a retracted front vowel [ɨ]. Are there no sound changes which could take an 甲類 /i/ to a 乙類 /i/ or vice versa? There is also the fact that 木 /ki/ alternates with /ko/ in some compounds while 黄 does not.

Comment: In the conjugation of verbs, yes, but not nouns. The fact that /i/ alternates with /o/ in 木 is just stronger evidence for 木 having a type-2 /ki/.

Comment: You say *"[a]ssuming these continue a historical distinction"*, so I have to ask: just how safe is that assumption?

Comment: You would have to ask an expert. 日本語国語大辞典 gives historical accentuation information for 黄 (different from 木, of course!) but for some reason it is marked with 「か」 as if the data is unreliable.

Comment: In 黄金 it is pronounced as /ko/ but also /ku/, while 木 is not. The 甲乙 distinction, while clear, is nowhere close to being resolved. I don't think it's safe to base speculations on more speculations

Comment: Basically, because many words in Japanese have the same sound and the き meaning "tree" is different from the き meaning "yellow".

Comment: Re: vowel alterations in 木 between こ and き, there are many such nouns that exhibit vowel fronting when used as standalone nouns, as mentioned [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14313/whats-the-relationship-between-e-and-wa-in-some-words/15993#15993).  I don't have any resources to hand that discuss 甲類 vs. 乙類, but I am very curious if anyone has information stating whether these vowel-fronting nouns usually become one or the other when fronted.

Comment: Zhen Lin, I'm a bit confused by your comment about pitch accent, in that you seem to be including the い from 色{いろ} in with the き from 木{き} and 黄{き}.  Presumably that's just for purposes of illustration?

Comment: Both 木 and 黃 were *ki2* in Old Japanese, but *i2* can come from Proto-Japonic *\*əy*, *\*oy* or *\*uy*. Based on comparisons with [Ryukyuan languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryukyuan_languages), it seems that some reconstructions of Proto-Japonic include *\*kəy* "tree" and *\*koy* "yellow".